# segregate the data based on their own value

Tags: vba

I have data where list is dynamic. I would like to segregate the data base on their own value.I am unable to predict the exact value coming every time. Example : - This time I got company code as 1959809 and 1960574. I would like to filter data based on company code and would like to paste it in new workbook. This number will get change every time. Next time the company code may be 1960574 and 1963665.

I am thinking that we need to group the company code value so that we can have it in variable. However, I am unable to get the logic.

I am not getting any logic to do so. Hence, I don't have anything to show.

We should get two or more workbooks based on company code along with respective data.

Comment: *"I have data where list is dynamic"* Where does it come from ?

Comment: Can you share the screenshot or sample data? it will help to understand the issue better. What I could understand you can use AutoFilter to filter your data based on company ID and paste it to a new sheet.

Comment: @DhirendraKumar no please, no screenshot.

Comment: There are a few ways, have you attempted anything?  You could use the macro recorder to use a filter and do what you need, then inspect the code generated by that.  Look at loops maybe, without any more information/screenshot, it's hard to advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your data has first column as 'Company Code' and starts from the first row of sheet, Following code will help you achieving your goal:

```
    Sub ExportFilteredData()
    Dim Codes As String, CodesArray, Code
    Dim Wb As Workbook, CurSht As Worksheet

    'Get the company codes from user as comma separated values
    Codes = InputBox("Enter Company codes separated by comma")
    CodesArray = Split(Codes, ",") 'Split company codes to array

    'Save the data sheet reference and remove any applied filter
    Set CurSht = ActiveSheet
    CurSht.AutoFilterMode = False

    'Filter data for each company code and save as new workbook
    For Each Code In CodesArray
        'Change the 'Field' value to the actual 'Company Code' column number 
        CurSht.Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Trim(Code)
        Set Wb = Workbooks.Add
        CurSht.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Wb.Sheets(1).Range("A1")
        'Change the path and filename as per your requirement    
        Wb.SaveAs ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Trim(Code) & ".xlsx"
        Wb.Close False
        CurSht.AutoFilterMode = False
    Next

    End Sub
```